# Sending mail through javamail api

Tags: jsp, jakarta-mail, netbeans-8

I am using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 , i want to send email to my gmail account from a JSP page. I have included jar files like javax.mail.jar ,activation.jar,smtp-1.5.4.jar ,javax.mail-api-1.5.4.jar and mailapi-1.5.4 in my libraries.
My JSP Code is:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%
      String result;
   // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "ambc@gmail.com";

 // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    String from = "saini@ifmail.com";

// Assuming you are sending email from localhost
   String host = "localhost";

// Get system properties object
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();

// Setup mail server
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);


// Get the default Session object.
  Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  try{
      // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
     // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                           new InternetAddress(to));
    // Set Subject: header field
       message.setSubject("My first localhost mail!");
   //  Now set the actual message
       message.setText("this is my first mail. hope it works");
   // Send message
       Transport.send(message);
      result = "Sent message successfully....";
     }catch (MessagingException mex) {
      mex.printStackTrace();
      result = "Error: unable to send message....";
     }
   %>
<html>
     <head>
        <title>Send Email using JSP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>Send Email using JSP</h1>
       </center>
     <p align="center">
        <% 
            out.println("Result: " + result + "\n");
        %>
      </p>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I always get error message:Result: Error: unable to send message....
Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Comment: You always get the error message that you print. That is of no use to use whatsoever. You need to provide the actual exception that was thrown, and the stack trace.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and [instructions for accessing Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to allow access to your gmail account from third party applications. I had this problem before. 
To allow access do the following:

1. Sign in to your gmail account and visit this page https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click on button to allow access.
2. Visit this page https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and enable access for less secure apps.